# How do you fix a door lever that won't fully retract the latch bolt?

Tags: doors, lock

My front door lock won't open when I depress the lever on the exterior of the door. That's because the lever isn't retracting the latch bolt fully enough. (See photo below of what it looks like while I'm depressing the lever.) When I turn the knob on the interior of the door, the latch bolt retracts correctly. Is this fixable?

[image]

Comment: Will need to take it apart to see what is worn down.  Might be 50/50 if fixing or replacing makes more sense.  Might get by just replacing the latch/centre section instead of the handles.

Comment: "Is this fixable" isn't a suitable question for this site. That's up to you. I suggest pulling it apart and seeing what you see. Then come back with a more specific question. Chances are it needs cleaning and lubrication, but who can say from this photo?

Answer (score 3):

The cam mechanism which retracts the latch is worn. In most cheap locks, replacing the latch unit is the easiest fix... If you can get the replacement; finding someone other than a locksmithing supply house who might sell just that one part may be tough.

Easy fix is slap in a replacement handleset, which will come with a new latch.